# Php MySQL Many to Many to Many condition Group By

Tags: php, mysql, group

I am creating a query between multiple many to many relationship tables in order to chain their values together. My issue is that I can't seem to figure a way to Group By the 'service' values from the 'services' sub-table in this query:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(containers.container_id ORDER BY containers.container_id DESC) AS container_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(containers.container_serial ORDER BY containers.container_id DESC) AS container_serial, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(containers.container_index ORDER BY containers.container_id DESC) AS container_index, 
    invoices.*, 
    statuses.status, 
    clients.client, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(services.service_id ORDER BY containers.container_id DESC) AS service_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(services.service ORDER BY containers.container_id DESC) AS service 
FROM containers_invoices 
LEFT JOIN containers 
    ON containers_invoices.container_id = containers.container_id 
LEFT JOIN invoices 
    ON containers_invoices.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN statuses 
    ON invoices.status_id = statuses.status_id 
LEFT JOIN clients 
    ON invoices.client_id = clients.client_id 
LEFT JOIN invoices_services 
    ON invoices.invoice_id = invoices_services.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN services 
    ON invoices_services.service_id = services.service_id 
GROUP BY containers_invoices.invoice_id 
ORDER BY invoice_id DESC
```

Right now my result looks something like this:

1. C09-65475u76u76, C08-dfsgreg345g3 -  114  -  ? -     Service,Service     - 1000  - Sent
2. C09-65475u76u76, C08-dfsgreg345g3, C03-dfsdfsd, C02-sadasd - 117     - ?  -  Line,Line,Line,Line -   3000 -  Paid

The service should show up only once and not loop as many times as the containers number that I have. I know I am close, but I can't seem to close that solution gap. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by invoice:

```
GROUP BY containers_invoices.invoice_id
```

You should group by service from what I understand

```
GROUP BY services.service_id
```

EDIT: I guess I misunderstood the question. You'd like to keep one row per invoice but in your group_concat not list mutliple times the same value.

If it is so, you can use the DISTINCT keyword:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT services.service ORDER BY containers.container_id DESC) AS service
```

Comment: No no, the invoice_id is the main value by which the Invoice table is grouped by. The order is something like this:
invoices -> containers_invoices -> containers
| invoices -> invoices_services -> services , the invoices collects the container data and the services data, the invoice can have one or more type of services (but not the same type) and more or more containers.

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood your question, can you give examples? Like what you are getting, and what you'd like to get. But not just one line, maybe 3-4?

Comment: sorry, I had to edit my answer multiple time above because I kept pressing enter and posting my message by accident, mid-sentence

Comment: HAHA, you are the Best. I love you! <3 Have a super wonderful day. That did the trick ^__^